# Converting array of pipe separated strings into map in ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

I am using the savon gem to deal with a really crappy soap response like:

```
["12|310|T02-260|", "14|130|T01-110|CAR 27", ...]
```

I need to split each of these at the pipe symbol and map them to a model attribute. Any suggestions?

Comment: How would I take what is split and map them to attributes in the model? e.g. [ :a => "12", :b => "310", :c => "T02-260"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you the array of hashes

```
fields = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
response.map{ |r| Hash[*fields.zip(r.split('|')).flatten] }
```

Result = `[ {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}, ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

As an example, suppose you need to get and set an id, sequence number and skw.
Would this help?

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :id, :seq, :skw

  def initialize(soap_res)
    %w{id seq skw}.zip(soap_res.split "|").each do |(attr, val)|
      self.send("#{attr}=", val)
    end
  end
end

1.9.3p194 :057 > f = Foo.new "12|310|T02-260"
 => #<Foo:0x007ff1ea8e0970 @id="12", @seq="310", @skw="T02-260">
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the given array be `soap_response`

```
def deal_with_pipe_symbols(soap_response)
  outer_array = []
  soap_response.each do |element|
    outer_array << element.split('|')
  end
  outer_array
end
```

This method should return an array that looks like below which is more workable.

`[['12','310','T02-260',''], ['14','130','T01-','CAR 27'], ...]`

Answer (score 0):

The CSV library in the stdlib should do this well (it understands quoting and so forth) Here I'm joining the lines but you can parse them independently, they will just be in a deeper array.

```
require 'csv'
inputs = ["12|310|T02-260|", "14|130|T01-110|\"CAR|27\""]
result = CSV.parse inputs.join("\n"), col_sep: '|'
result # => [["12", "310", "T02-260", nil], ["14", "130", "T01-110", "CAR|27"]]
```